# Existence (or non) of "definable" ultrafilters

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, ultrafilters, descriptive-set-theory

This is a question which I suspect has an absurdly easy answer, but I'm not seeing it.

Let $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle:\omega^2\rightarrow\omega$ be your favorite pairing map (for me, this is the Cantor pairing function $(x, y)\mapsto{(x+y)(x+y+1)\over 2}+y$). Then, for $\mathcal{U}$ any ultrafilter on $\omega$, we can define a map $$m_\mathcal{U}: \mathcal{P}(\omega)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(\omega): X\mapsto\lbrace j: \lbrace i: \langle i, j\rangle\in X\rbrace\in \mathcal{U}\rbrace.$$ The intuition behind this, for me, is that we take $X$, decompose it into rows, and treat each row as a guess at a mysterious set $\hat{X}$. The actual set $\hat{X}$ is the set of all natural numbers $j$ such that "most" of the rows of $X$ guess that $j$ is in $\hat{X}$. Topologically speaking, these maps are very badly behaved (unless $\mathcal{U}$ is principal of course); I don't know of any good picture of them besides this guessing idea.

This lets $\mathcal{U}$ act on collections of sets of natural numbers: for $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, let $$\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{C})=\lbrace m_\mathcal{U}(X): X\in\mathcal{C}\rbrace.$$ Mild closure properties of $\mathcal{C}$ imply that for all ultrafilters $\mathcal{U}$, we have $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{C})\supseteq\mathcal{C}$; in the other direction, it is easy to construct, for any ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ and any $\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, a $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega)$ such that $\mathcal{D}\subseteq\mathcal{C}$ and $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}$.

I'm playing around with these maps for the heck of it; I don't know of any mathematical significance they have (although I'd be very interested if someone could point me towards a source where they're already studied). While fooling around, I ran into the following question:

Let $\mathcal{C}\subseteq\mathcal{P}(\omega)$. Say that an ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ on $\omega$ is *definable in $\mathcal{C}$* if $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{C})=\mathcal{C}$ and there is some formula $\phi$ with parameters from $\mathcal{C}\cup\omega$ and two free set variables $\phi(X, Y)$ in the language of second-order arithmetic such that $$\forall A, B\in\mathcal{C}, m_\mathcal{U}(A)=B\iff (\omega,\mathcal{C})\models\phi(A, B).$$ (In this case, say $\mathcal{U}$ is definable in $\mathcal{C}$ via $\phi$) My question is this:

(*) What are the $\mathcal{C}$, $\mathcal{U}$ such that $\mathcal{U}$ is definable in $\mathcal{C}$?

Principal ultrafilters are definable in reasonable $\mathcal{C}$, but I can't "construct" an example of any non-principal ultrafilter being definable in any $\mathcal{C}$ that isn't stupid (say, $\mathcal{C}=\lbrace A\rbrace$, $m_\mathcal{U}(A)=A$, so $\phi(X, Y)\equiv X=Y$); on the other hand, I have no reason to believe that nontrivial examples don't exist.

There is also the stronger notion of *extendible definability*: An ultrafilter $\mathcal{U}$ is *extendibly definable in $\mathcal{C}$* if for some formula $\phi$, $\mathcal{U}$ is definable in $\mathcal{C}$ via $\phi$ and for all $\mathcal{D}\supseteq\mathcal{C}$, there is some $\mathcal{E}\supseteq \mathcal{D}$ such that $\mathcal{U}$ is definable in $\mathcal{E}$ via $\phi$. For instance, every principal ultrafilter is extendibly definable in any sufficiently closed $\mathcal{C}$.

(**) Are there any examples of non-principal ultrafilters being extendibly definable?

A negative answer to this question is plausible to me, I just have no idea how to approach this.

Thanks!

Comment: David: Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I managed to miss that completely. Fixed!

Comment: That $m_\cal U$ map looks very familiar. It reminds me addition or multiplication of ultrafilters maybe.

Comment: @Asaf: How so? I don't think I see the connection.

Comment: Well, not quite that I suppose. On the looks of it (although I did not butcher through the details) it seems that if $\cal F$ is an ultrafilter then $\cal U(F)$ is an ultrafilter as well. Maybe that's true and then it's worth to check how does the map which sends an ultrafilter to its associated function behaves with addition. Maybe that will help uncover answers regarding the definability questions.

Comment: I think I agree with you that $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{F})$ for $\mathcal{F}$ an ultrafilter is an ultrafilter. That for all $Y$, $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{F})$ contains $Y$ or $\omega-Y$: given $Y\subseteq\omega$, consider the set $X=\lbrace \langle i, j\rangle: j\in Y\rbrace$. Then $\omega-X=\lbrace \langle i, j\rangle: j\not\in Y\rbrace$, and no matter what $\mathcal{U}$ is we have $\mathcal{U}(X)=Y$ and $\mathcal{U}(\omega-X)=\omega-Y$. Since $\mathcal{F}$ is an ultrafilter, either $X$ or $\omega-X$ is in $\mathcal{F}$, hence either $Y$ or $\omega-Y$ is in $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{F})$.

Comment: A nice property of $\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{F})$: As a map $\beta\mathbb{N}$ to $\beta\mathbb{N}$, it's actually continuous: $Y\in\mathcal{U}(\mathcal{F})$ if and only if $\lbrace \langle i, j\rangle: j\in Y\rbrace\in \mathcal{F}$, so the preimage of a basic open set is open. But beyond that, I don't see any other nice properties of this map to suggest an analogy with ultrafilter addition?

Comment: Well, I never said that "reminds me" means "is very similar", association schemes in the mind work in mysterious ways... Regardless to that, the fact it's a continuous function is a very interesting fact (I think it somewhat shows that this is a relatively natural operator to consider). This might come in handy later on...

Comment: Yes, what's going on with $m_\cal U$ seems to be the following: fix a recursive bijection, Cantor pairing function, its inverse takes $n$ to $(n_0,n_1)$. Send $X \subset \mathbb{N}$ to the set of all $j$ which satisfy the following: for any $n \in X$, if $j=n_1$, the set of $n_0$ such that $(n_0,j) \in X$ should be "big",i.e look at all the 2nd coordinates of the members of $X$ and for each of them, check if the set of all 1st coordinates that can possibly be associated with them such that they code a member of $X$ is big. If yes, send $X$ to that particular set of second coordinates.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed the definition of the map $m_\mathcal{U}$.